# Yii: How to sum grid column in header

Tags: yii, cgridview

I need to `sum` the three columns (Budget, Release and Expenditure), and put the total in under the filter boxes or in header.

```
| Fund | Budget | Release | Expenditure|
----------------------------------------
| A    | 10     | 5       | 3          |
----------------------------------------
| B    | 20     | 10      | 5          |
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an extra column at your gridview

array(
            'header'=>'Total',
            'filter'=>'',
            'value'=>'($data->budget + $data->release + $data->expenditure)',
        )